# How to return Observable from subscriber?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, rx-java, observable

I am using rxJava first time in my application I am trying to achieve following implementation :

1. fetch account from 3rd party server
2. fetch account from local DB
3. compare account and filter out those account which is not in local DB
4. save only those accounts in local db which is not in local DB.

Here is my code :-

```
 private Observable<List<Result<Account, IError>>> filterAccounts(Context context, List<Account> accounts){


         accountDAL.getByIds(context, accounts
                .stream()
                .map(a -> Long.valueOf(a.getAccountId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))//return Observable<List<T>> getByIds(Context context, List<Long> ids)
                .map( a -> {
                    Map<Long, SearchConnectAccount> map = a.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.getId(), Function.identity())); // map ==> {id = Account}

                 return map;
                }).subscribe( seMap -> { // subscribe observable

                  List<Account> filteredList = accounts.stream()
                             .filter(a -> seMap.get(Long.valueOf(a.getAccountId())) == null)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());

Observable<List<Result<Account, IError>>> o = accountDAL.save(context, filteredList).first();
                    return o;//accountDAL.save(context, filteredList).first();

         });

        // how to return Observable<List<Result<Account, IError>>> from here
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
private Observable<List<Result<Account, IError>>> filterAccounts(Context context, List<Account> accounts){
     return accountDAL.getByIds(context, accounts
            .stream()
            .map(a -> Long.valueOf(a.getAccountId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .map(a -> 
                 a.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.getId(), Function.identity())) // map ==> {id = Account}

            ).map(seMap -> 
               accountDAL.save(context, accounts.stream()
                     .filter(a -> seMap.get(Long.valueOf(a.getAccountId())) == null)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList())).first());
}
```

**Update**

The 2nd call to `save` returns an `Observable<?>` (just an assumption) and when it is wrapped in a `map` operator it returns `Observable<Observable<?>>`. But what you need as a return value is `Observable<?>`. So you need to flatten the `Observable<Observable<?>>` into `Observable<?>` and that's where `flatMap` is used. Here's the updated answer in case if needed.

```
private Observable<List<Result<Account, IError>>> filterAccounts(Context context, List<Account> accounts) {
        return accountDAL
                .getByIds(context,
                        accounts.stream().map(a -> Long.valueOf(a.getAccountId())).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .map(ar -> ar.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Account::getAccountId, Function.identity())) // map ==>
                                                                                                            // {id =
                // Account}

                ).flatMap(seMap -> accountDAL.save(context, accounts.stream()
                        .filter(a -> seMap.get(Long.valueOf(a.getAccountId())) == null).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
```

Comment: its showing compile time error => missing return statement

Comment: In which line you get this?

Comment: in last block ->                              no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Observable<List<Result<Account, IError>>> conforms to List<Result<Account, IError>> inference variable R has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: List<Result<Account, IError>> lower bounds: Observable<List<Result<Account, IError>>>

Comment: Sorry, But I am facing same issue in last map block, Updated question

Comment: Could you please see now